# Crear MultiChoice AlertDialog en Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, diálogo

En el `ActionBar` necesito implementar un `AlertDialog` con múltiples opciones el cual se llene por medio de un `ArrayList` con un Array Adapter, y los datos yo los obtengo desde un WebService implementando la clase `AsyncTask`.

Necesito que me expliquen o ayude a decirme como implemento ese `AlertDialog`, por el momento tengo un `AlertDialog` en la pantalla que necesito con los datos de prueba que yo ingrese, pero necesito llenarlo con los datos de mi WebService.

Anexo la imagen del `AlertDialog`.

Por cierto como extra necesito obtener los datos que el usuario marca y manejarlos en la Activity.

Agrego código mi `menusetting` donde tengo icono que uso para abrir mi `alertdialog`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Clientes">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:hint="Buscar Cliente"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    //item que uso para Alertdialog
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/filtro"
        android:title="@string/filtro"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Código donde Creo el `AlertDialog` con los datos ficticios

```
public void EligirZona(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);{
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        // String array for alert dialog multi choice items
        String[] colors = new String[]{
                "Norte",
                "Sur",
                "Metropolitana",

        };

        // Boolean array for initial selected items
        final boolean[] checkedColors = new boolean[]{
                false, // Norte
                true, // Sur
                false, // Metropolitana
        };

        // Convert the color array to list
        final List<String> colorsList = Arrays.asList(colors);
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(colors, checkedColors, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                // Update the current focused item's checked status
                checkedColors[which] = isChecked;

                // Get the current focused item
                String currentItem = colorsList.get(which);

                // Notify the current action
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        currentItem + " " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Specify the dialog is not cancelable
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        // Set a title for alert dialog
        builder.setTitle("Selecciona la Zona(s) que Visitaras");

        // Set the positive/yes button click listener
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when click positive button
                /*tv.setText("La Zona Seleccionada es..... \n");
                for (int i = 0; i<checkedColors.length; i++){
                    boolean checked = checkedColors[i];
                    if (checked) {
                        tv.setText(tv.getText() + colorsList.get(i) + "\n");
                    }
                }*/
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"La Zona Seleccionada es", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });

        // Set the negative/no button click listener
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when click the negative button
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Set the neutral/cancel button click listener
        builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when click the neutral button
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        // Display the alert dialog on interface
        dialog.show();
       }
    }
```

Código donde mando a llamar el diálogo

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // action with ID action_refresh was selected
            case R.id.action_favorite:
                /*SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                AsyncZona task = new AsyncZona(settings.getString("ONControlWSURL", "").toString());
                //Call execute
                task.execute();*/
               EligirZona();
                break;


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Código donde mando a llamar el método que necesito el cual contiene la información que llenará el `alertdialog`, ahora solo tengo la construcción de la clase

```
 private class AsyncZona extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, ArrayList>
    {
        private String ONControlWSURL;
        public AsyncZona(String ONControlWSURL)
        {
            this.ONControlWSURL = ONControlWSURL;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
            ZonaArrayList = new ArrayList<Zona>();
            webService O_WS = new webService(ONControlWSURL);
            ZonaArrayList=O_WS.Zona();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
            super.onPostExecute(arrayList);

            if(ZonaArrayList.size()!=0){

                /*Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.menu_spinner1);
                ArrayAdapter<FormaPago> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<FormaPago>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, PagoArrayList);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);*/

            }else{

            }
        }
    }
```

Nuevo código

```
 public void EligirZona() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);
    {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
        AsyncZona task = new AsyncZona(settings.getString("ONControlWSURL", "").toString());
        //Call execute
        task.execute();

        // Boolean array for initial selected items
        final boolean[] checkedColors = new boolean[]{
                false, // Norte
                true, // Sur
                false, // Metropolitana
        };

        // Convert the color array to list
        // final List<String> colorsList = Arrays.asList(colors);
        final ArrayList<Zona> ZonaArrayList = new ArrayList<Zona>();

        String[] colors = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
        colors = ZonaArrayList.toArray(colors);


        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(colors, checkedColors, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                // Update the current focused item's checked status
                checkedColors[which] = isChecked;

            }
        });

        builder.setCancelable(false);

        // Set a title for alert dialog
        builder.setTitle("Selecciona la Zona(s) que Visitaras");

        // Set the positive/yes button click listener
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when click positive button
            /*tv.setText("La Zona Seleccionada es..... \n");
            for (int i = 0; i<checkedColors.length; i++){
                boolean checked = checkedColors[i];
                if (checked) {
                    tv.setText(tv.getText() + colorsList.get(i) + "\n");
                }
            }*/
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"La Zona Seleccionada es", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });

        // Set the negative/no button click listener
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when click the negative button
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Set the neutral/cancel button click listener
        builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when click the neutral button
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        // Display the alert dialog on interface
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

[image: Screen]

Comment: Agrega el código.

Comment: ok, gracias por el comentario lo tomare en cuenta y una disculpa

Comment: ya agregue el codigo

Comment: Alguien que me pueda apoyar???

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente contestaré tu pregunta principal. Existen varias formas de realizarlo, puede ser un DialogFragment, pero veo que tienes una especie de settings a definir, aquí podría ser un Preference Activity o un Activity, el es punto importante es el tema, para poder tener un background con cierta opacidad.

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#fff0f0f0</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#ffe0e0e0</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ff555555</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ff808080</item>
</style>
```

Este tema lo agregarías a tu Activity dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"/>
```

Para lograr obtener algo como:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cuanto a los datos, veo que los obtienes en el AsyncTask y la variable es:
`ZonaArrayList` y la cual si la defines como global en tu Activity, puedes asignarla en esta linea, copiando el contenido de `ZonaArrayList` en `colorsList` y también convertir el ArrayList a un Array llamado colors  :

```
public void EligirZona(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);{
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        // String array for alert dialog multi choice items
       /* String[] colors = new String[]{
                "Norte",
                "Sur",
                "Metropolitana",

        }; */

        // Boolean array for initial selected items
        final boolean[] checkedColors = new boolean[]{
                false, // Norte
                true, // Sur
                false, // Metropolitana
        };

        // Convert the color array to list
      // final List<String> colorsList = Arrays.asList(colors);        
       final List<String> colorsList = new ArrayList<String>(ZonaArrayList);

String[]   colors = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
 colors = ZonaArrayList.toArray(colors);


        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(colors, checkedColors, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                // Update the current focused item's checked status
                checkedColors[which] = isChecked;

                // Get the current focused item
                String currentItem = colorsList.get(which);

                // Notify the current action
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        currentItem + " " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

....
....
```

Comment: hola, ya agregue mi codigo, gracias por lo del theme pero ahora si que mi duda es como llego mi alert dialog con mis datos que bienen de un webservices?

Comment: gracias... o alguna propuesta mejor de como lo puedo aplicar no estoy cerrado, yo lo tengo pensado hacer asi por que he usado los alertdialog

Comment: Listo, con respecto a los datos copia el contenido de tu ArrayList ZonaArrayList  a colorsList  con eso se veran los datos en tu Dialogo.

Comment: no esos son datos de pruebas como genero un string de prueba de colores solo para ver como se visualizara los datos en el alertdialog

Comment: ArrayList<Zona> ZonaArrayList = new ArrayList<Zona>(); este es mi array que debo de usar ya que tengo una clase llamada Zona

Comment: si agregaste tu respuesta Elenasys?

Comment: Dentro de EligirZona() se tienen que realizar algunos cambios a partir de ZonaArrayList para desplegar tus datos, revisa.

Comment: Y en mi OnpostExecute ya no haga nada?

Comment: Si ya tienes datos en ZonaArrayList  ya no, de hecho creo que se llena el ArrayList en doInBackground

Comment: si es asi... yo uso el doInBackground para mandar a llamar el metodo del webservices, y esos datos los guardo en un objeto de arraylist y en el OnpostExecute es donde llenaria mi alertdialog, bueno asi lo tenia pensado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40675/discussion-between-hugo-rodriguez-and-elenasys).

Comment: ta trate de hacerlo pero no puedo.. adjunto codigo de como lo tengo