# ¿Cómo puedo crear un Dialogo en android?

Tags: android, alertdialog, diálogo

Me gustaría iniciar un Dialogo al oprimir mi botón de agregar para poder
confirmar.

```
public class AddClientActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button agregarButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_client);

        addClientBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_agregar);
        addClientBtn.setOnClickListener(this);


    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.btn_agregar) {

         // CREAR DIALOGO *****************

         }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En el sitio puedes encontrar varios ejemplos como son:

[Cambiar color de texto en un AlertDialog](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/44504/cambiar-color-de-texto-en-un-alertdialog)

[Create MultiChoice AlertDialog in Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/11630/create-multichoice-alertdialog-in-android)

Esta es la forma de crear un Dialogo, con botones para aceptar y cancelar:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

// Configura el titulo.
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Mi Dialogo");

// Configura el mensaje.
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Hola Alex, ¿aceptas la opción?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Si",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

             //Si la respuesta es afirmativa aquí agrega tu función a realizar.
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                 dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).create().show();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

En tu código se implementaría de esta forma:

```
    ...
    ...
    public void onClick(View v) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddClientActivity.this);    
// Configura el titulo.
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Mi Dialogo");   
// Configura el mensaje.
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Hola Alex, ¿aceptas la opción?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Si",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {    
                        //Si la respuesta es afirmativa aquí agrega tu función a realizar.
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).create().show();


    }
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Para crear un dialogo puedes usar el "AlertDialog.Builder". 
Primero defines el builder, después le añades un titulo, un mensaje que sera el texto que va bajo del titulo y los botones, positivo o negativo. Aparte también se pueden añadir mas elementos como editText o listview.
Te dejo un ejemplo básico:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Titulo del dialogo");
    builder.setMessage("Texto descriptivo...");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Hacer cosas aqui al hacer clic en el boton de aceptar     
        }
    });
    builder.show();
```

Aquí te dejo un enlace para la documentación de android donde te lo explican bastante bien.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

Lo que he realizado para crear mi Dialogo fué implementar lo siguiente dentro del onClickListener de la actividad  en donde quiero implementar el dialogo (**en mi caso esta actividad no es el MainActivity)**:

```
    DialogFragment newFragment = new ClientDialogFragment();
            newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Agregar Cliente");
```

quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
'public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btn_agregar) {
       DialogFragment newFragment = new ClientDialogFragment();
       newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
       newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Agregar Cliente");
    }
 }
```

Como podemos ver utilizé un fragmento, el cual lo implementé de la siguiente manera:

1. crear fragmento: File/new/Fragment/ Fragmento(Blank)
2. Nombre: ClientDialogFragment

   ```
   public class ClientDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {  
         @Override
         public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
      AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
      builder.setMessage("Cuerpo del dialogo"))
           .setTitle("Titulo del Dialogo")
           .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
                        /*
                         * La acción que implementé fue regresarme
                         *  al MainActivity
                         */
                       getActivity().finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   /**
                    ** Dialogo Cancelado, Regresa a la actividad anterior
                    */
               }
           });

   return builder.create();
   }
   ```

   }

Y mi código XML Fue:

```
    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment  -->
    <FrameLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>

     </FrameLayout>
```

Y Listo !
Este fue mi resultado, espero que les sirva.

[image: Mi resultado del dialogo]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es un cuadro de dialog, o Alert dialog. el cual es el mensaje que aparece en el centro de la pantalla al realizar alguna opcion, el cual nos da una información y nos da varias opciones o simplemente el mensaje.

```
Context context = this;

    AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); 
    alertdialog.setMessage("aqui colocas el mensaje")
    .setCancelable(false)// Aqui defines que no se pueda dar atras (cancelar el dialog) el usuario debera seleccionar una opcion
    .setPositiveButton(" texto Boton positivo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // agrega aqui la funcion que quieres hacer con el boton positivo
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("texto boton negativo", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // agrega aqui la funcion que quieres hacer con el boton negativo
        }
    });
AlertDialog mensaje = alertdialog.create();
    mensaje.show();
```

Answer (score -1):

Los anteriores ejemplos se basan en el `AlertDialogBuilder`.
Pero también se puede crear uno personalizado con su propio xml, y que en java sería así:

```
public class TuFragment extends DialogFragment {
...
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tu_fragment, container, false);
        tit = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        agregar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        cancelar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);

return v;
 ...
```

No es como el fragment "normal"  que se puede agregar a la pila (`addToBackStack`).

Y no olvidar agragar el método `dismiss();` (por ejemplo al hacer click en los botones agregar y cancelar) para que el dialogo se cierre.