# He creado un dialogo en Android, ¿cómo puedo darle formato al texto? (En negritas o letras mas grandes)

Tags: android, diálogo

Recientemente he logrado mostrar un dialogo en android, he pedido un poco de ayuda para lograr hacerlo y las respuestas son muy buenas, la pregunta está en el siguiente enlace:
[¿Cómo puedo crear un Dialogo en android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80852/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-crear-un-dialogo-en-android)

Pero ahora me gustaría poder darle formato. por ejemplo en el cuerpo del
Dialogo poner una parte **en negritas** para destacar información o incluso  poner alguna palabra o frase con un **tamaño más grande**.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr el resultado deseado utilicé: `Html.fromHtml()`.

¿Cómo se implementa?

Dentro del fragmento de dialogo:

1. Termina linea `<br>` (para salto de linea, así como `\n`).
2. `<big> Texto más grande </big>`
3. `<b>Texto en negritas </b>`

En el código implementado se vería:

```
builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("El servicio dará inicio a las: <br><br>"+
       "<big>"+ 10 +" (aproximadamente)</big>" +
       " <br><br>Le sugerimos estar al pendiente"))
       .setTitle("¿Agregar item? ") ...
```

Código completo dentro del framento:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
    AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("El servicio dará inicio a las: <br><br>"+
            "<big>"+ 10 +" (aproximadamente)</big>" +
            " <br><br>Le sugerimos estar al pendiente"))
            .setTitle("¿Agregar item?")
    .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
                 /*
                  * La acción que implementé fue regresarme
                  *  al MainActivity
                  */
                getActivity().finish();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            /**
             ** Dialogo Cancelado, Regresa a la actividad anterior
             */
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

El resultado fue este:

[image: Resultado]