# ¿Cómo, mediante Firebase, puedo "obligar" al usuario a actualizar la aplicación Android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, update, actualizacion

Estoy haciendo una app para Android, pero no la subí a la Play Store. La app está escrita en Kotlin.

Me gustaría que, cada vez que hiciera una nueva versión de la aplicación, pudiera salir un mensaje de alerta, diciendo que hay una nueva versión y que debe instalarla para seguir usando la app. Preferiblemente debería poderlo hacer usando Firebase.

He revisado muchísimas webs de internet y videos, pero todos lo hacen con Java. Sólo encontré un tutorial en Kotlin ([este](https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/firebase-remote-config-for-app-updates-check-81379ff96cd1)) pero me perdí en el punto 4.

Me gustaría preguntarles si alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo, es bastante importante para mí conseguir hacer eso. Lo intenté todo, pero no lo conseguí. Y, si es posible, me interesaría usar Firebase.

Saludos, y muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Tupí que tal con tu app? Estoy en la misma situación prefiero no publicarlo de momento en play store? Y quería saber si hay forma de eliminar el mensaje de fuentes desconocidas al descargar la APK desde storage

Comment: Hola Maia, puedes realizar una pregunta haciendo referencia a esta y exponer tu problematica para que tenga mejor visibilidad, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que realiza Firebase es crear un Remote Config, donde incluye información relacionada a la aplicación, en este caso puedes definir la versión actual de produción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es algo similar a un método que usaba anteriormente, a partir de un archivo de configuración que lee el dispositivo al arrancar la app que contiene la última versión publicada de la app:

```
{
"myapp": {
"ver": "2.1",
 ...
 ...
 }
}
```

Comparando esta versión definida en el archivo .json con la de la app (`BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)`) se puede determinar si la app instalada necesita o no actualización.

```
   if (configVersion < Double.parseDouble(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)){
      //Actualiza.
    }else{
      //NO Actualiza.
    }
```

de esta forma puedes crear un Dialogo el cual te sugerira actualizar o no, si debes actualizar te cargaría la url de tu app en la playstore

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mydominio.myapplicacion
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para abrir la Play Store y redirigir a actualizar usa un Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<paquete de aplicacion>"));
startActivity(i);.
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por tu solución! Es lo que busco. Sólo tengo dos dudas: Mi app no está en la Play Store. ¿Puedo redirigir al usuario a otra web para eso, por ejemplo los releases de GitHub, o sería mejor usar el Cloud Storage de Firebase? La otra, ¿qué tipo de diálogo sería el mejor en este caso? Otra vez, muchas gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: Puedes redirigir al usuario a otra url fuera de Google Play pero la dificultad aquí es que el usuario debe activar en los settings la "descarga desde ubicaciones desconocidas", hay usuarios que no estan muy familiarizados con la configuración, lo mejor es redirigir a la página de la playstore de tu app. El dialogo puede ser un AlertDialog como este ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/80866/95   y usa el código que agregue a la respuesta para abrir la PlayStore.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, realmente me ayudó. Lamentablemente no puedo subirla a la Play Store, así que el sistema que me diste me va genial. A todo esto, ¿con el Cloud Storage, podría subir ahí la app? Pensé que al ser la misma app podría no necesitar activar esos permisos.

Comment: Claro que si, puedes subir el .apk y exponer la url que será usada por los usuarios para instalar o actualizar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo que eso es todo. Cualquier otra cosa pregunto aquí.

Comment: Claro que si @Tupi , aquí hay varias personas en la comunidad que conocen Android y te pueden ayudar en lo que desees, saludos.

Comment: Saludos, tengo otra duda. Conseguí hacer eso, y conseguí descargar un archivo .apk del Storage de Firebase. ¿Hay alguna forma de abrir ese archivo descargado?